# Как записать Эмодзи в базу mysql с нормальным хранением вместо "?"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ребята, мучаюсь уже второй день.
Не записывает эмодзи в базу.
Соеденение правильное, пробовал разные кодировки базы и таблиц.
ДАже напрямую через пхпмайдмин закидываю эмодзи и отображает только версии юникод 1.

Остальные сохраняются как знаки вопроса "?"

Всю кодировку utf8mb4 перепробовал. Я техподдержку хоста уже утомил)) Админ сам пробовал и говорит что не знает в чем проблема...

Может их нужно конвертировать/кодировать или они поддятгиваются с других библитек. Инфы не нашел, первый раз с этим вопросом сталкнулся.

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Вот что пишет сервер по запросу `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю это на стороне хоста админ должен править?
Или можно в пхпмайадмине сделать?
Админ морозится и говорит что дело в подключении к базе.
Или не хочет ничего делать или сам не знает...

Comment: Укажите точную версию MySQL, точное наименование и версию используемого клиента (желательно использование CLI), а для клиента командной строки также текущий CHCP. Покажите вывод: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';`, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%coll%';`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE имя_таблицы;`, точный текст запроса INSERT, точный текст запроса SELECT, возвращающего знаки вопроса.

Comment: Дело в том что в базу записывается как вопросы

Comment: Версия сервера: 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log - (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте у конкретного нужного вам поля в таблице utf8mb4_general_ci.

Comment: я же написал что перепробовал все кодировки везде...

Comment: @Vladik Написал "разные кодировки базы и таблиц", про поля в таблице не писал